# PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues throws exception; handwritten code to do same works fine. What's happening behind the scenes to cause the error?

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have been bothered with this error message for 3 days:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dslomer64.sqhell, PID: 20613
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{com.dslomer64.sqhell/com.dslomer64.sqhell.MainActivity}: 
  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

It occurs in this line:

```
  PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences_no_table, true);
```

So I have no idea which variable caused it. A few days and a couple of rewrites ago, the same error occurred in trying to do this:

```
editor.putInt(PREF_ROWS, DEFAULT_ROWS);
```

No changes to `xml`. Of possible interest: `PREF_ROWS` was not in the original preferences file, with which I'd had no errors that I can recall.

Might it be that in trying to deal with `PREF_ROWS` (`"pref_rows"` in the xml file), `PreferenceManager` is running into whatever was causing that problem for me back then? But I'm having no such problem tonight.

Here's `preferences_no_table.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<ListPreference
    android:key         ="pref_rows"
    android:defaultValue="@integer/defaultrows_no_table"
    android:persistent   ="true"/>

<ListPreference
    android:key         ="pref_max_matches"
    android:defaultValue="@integer/defaultmaxmatches"
    android:entries     ="@array/matches_list"
    android:entryValues ="@array/matches_list"
    android:persistent  ="true"       />

<ListPreference
    android:key           ="pref_shortest_word"
    android:defaultValue="@integer/defaultshortestword"
    android:entries     ="@array/word_lengths"
    android:entryValues ="@array/word_lengths"
    android:persistent  ="true"/>  

<ListPreference
    android:key="pref_longest_word"
    android:defaultValue="@integer/defaultlongestword"
    android:entries     ="@array/word_lengths"
    android:entryValues ="@array/word_lengths"
    android:persistent="true"/>

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="pref_scrabble"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:persistent="true"        />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="pref_spell_check"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:enabled="false"/>

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="pref_dic_test"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:persistent="true"  />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key         ="pref_db_ready"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:persistent  ="true"/>

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key         ="pref_want_scoring"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:persistent  ="true"        />
```

Here's `integerdefaults.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <integer name="defaultmaxmatches">     100  </integer>
        <integer name="defaultshortestword">     2  </integer>
        <integer name="defaultlongestword">     14  </integer>
        <integer name="defaultrows_no_table">   -1  </integer>
        <integer name="defaultrows_empty_table"> 0  </integer>
    </resources>
```

I don't see how `arrays.xml`, which contains the values for 3 of the `ListPreferences` could cause the problem so it's omitted.

So I made my own method to set the defaults and called it like so:

```
myClearAndSetDefaultsAsInXml();
```

Here's the code:

```
  private void myClearAndSetDefaultsAsInXml(){ //SET PREFS TO ORIGINAL DEFAULTS
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    spDump("in pref clear and set my def");
    editor.clear();
    spDump("after editor clear");
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_DB_READY,      false);
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_DIC_TEST,      false);
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_SCRABBLE,      true);
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_WANT_SCORING,  false);
    editor.putInt    (PREF_ROWS,          DEFAULT_ROWS);
    editor.putInt    (PREF_MAX_MATCHES,   DEFAULT_MATCHES);
    editor.putInt    (PREF_LONGEST_WORD,  DEFAULT_LONGEST_WORD);
    editor.putInt    (PREF_SHORTEST_WORD, DEFAULT_SHORTEST_WORD);

    setBooleanPref(KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES, true);        
    editor.commit();
    spDump("end of myPrefSetDefaults");
  }
```

The `spDump` lines were for debugging. Turns out I didn't need them because the above code ran with no problems. Then I removed the call to my line removed and replaced it by the original `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues`. And got the same error. What is going on inside this method? Why do I have no problems but the preferred line of code does?

There is a database involved and it's not been opened at the particular point where the error occurs, but `SQLiteDatabase` and `SharedPreferences` don't talk to each other directly anyway. That's my job (e.g., to allow user to set different values for any of the prefs and keep those values until changed by user).

Something about the way I am handling preferences is obviously wrong. But what?

Here's the relevant part of `onCreate` in `MainActivity`:

```
@Override protected void        onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  sp = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);

  PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences_no_table, true); 
  mDatabase = myGetDatabase();
}
```

(`sp` is defined like so:   `static SharedPreferences sp;`)

P.S. Same error with `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences_no_table, false);`

Comment: I have never tried using `ListPreference` with anything but strings. Are you sure that `ListPreference` is supposed to work with integers for its value?

Comment: This doesn't deserve an answer, yeah as @CommonsWare stated, ListPreferences uses only strings, behind the scenes the array you have are basically strings, Behind the scenes it's trying to cast an Integer to String which is just not possible. One quick workaround is defining your resources as string and then getting their value with Integer.valueOf(arrrayEntry)

Comment: No, @CommonsWare, I'm not sure. I need list capability and 'ListPreference` had been the type I'd used for literally years and I originally did the usual `parseInt` deal String`s. But a revision has been unkind so frustration suggested the change. I'm going to keep it as is and see if it works and I'll be sure to report back once it's bug-free or rewritten for the third time this week. So far it has worked fine except for the error message, which I've worked around. I'll Google `ListPreference with numeric data` and see. Or maybe `Preference` alllows lists to be defined.

Comment: @Reda, you don't deserve a courteous response such as I gave Commonsware because he attacked the problem by asking a kind question, not by being judgemental and downright cruel. But I can be as faux-courteous as the next guy (as long as he's not you), so here goes. As I said to C'ware, I've done the `parseInt` thing, I'm aware of it; I figured if Android doesn't give errors in xml, I'm maybe good to go. But if it throws exceptions, well, revise. I don't want to do so helter-skelter, so I'll ask: do you think changing all the ListPreference occurrences to Preference will make any difference?

Comment: "do you think changing all the ListPreference occurrences to Preference will make any difference?" -- a `Preference` does not show a list, so I do not see how `Preference` can be a substitute. I also do not know that `Preference` itself *has* a value, let alone its type. If you wanted, you could roll an `IntListPreference`, either as a subclass or a fork of `ListPreference`, where values are saved as integers.

Comment: @CommonsWare--Yeah, changing to `Preference` was another thought at the same level as others I was having for those days. Stupid. Worth a try. One change, one error, abandon ship. AND I wish I had seen your suggestion of a custom preference before abandoning the whole idea of forcing `int`s into a `String` holes. So I deleted the database file `/data/user/0/com.dslomer64.sqhell/databases/dictionary` and the preferences file `/data/user/0/com.dslomer64.sqhell/shared_prefs/preferences.xml` and started over. No problems now, except having same brain that was so frickin' confused.

Comment: @CommonsWare,,, the more I think about it, I think I will try your idea. I've already done similar, extending `EditText` into `CustomEditText`. I've been whining about all the time I wasted trying to do what you warned would ultimately fail. I thought I "had it" (forced it) by trapping the "can't convert string into integer" inside pref change listener and ignoring the error--worked fine until ... hell, I don't remember exactly what error I got--probably the same--but I threw my hands up and started going back to all `Strings` with `parseInt` as needed. Thanks for your thoughts.